Error Could not find or load main class net.seninp.grammarviz.GrammarVizGUI
I'm trying to run grammarviz algorithm for anomaly detection. I applied all the steps mentioned in https://github.com/GrammarViz2/grammarviz2_src .
However, when I pasted the following command in the command prompt.
<java -Xmx4g -jar target/grammarviz2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar>

I got the following error.
Error: Could not find or load main class net.seninp.grammarviz.GrammarVizGUI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.seninp.grammarviz.GrammarVizGUI

I'm new to the java. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.
